# How to disable function name on report

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have a little problem with function name when generating documentation. When I use

```
.. autofunction:: annotation
```

I end up with function description and also function name. When generating documentation I do not want to show function (or module, or class) names but use only their description.
I was looking through sphinx python scripts but didn't found anything.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: *"I want not to show function (or module, or class) name"* - why on earth not?

Comment: Programmers will input description (tables with content, little description of target functionality, or what specific key do in conf file etc.) to function when adding changes to it. Then it will be added to specific place in documentation. Target reader of documentation will be someone that not need to know functions name, and only need to know what we want him to now, and the function name is one of the things that he don`t need to. Functions name will be displayed only in developers documentation, not in the user manual.

Comment: Then that information should be in a separate document; the way you're currently creating it suits API/developer documentation, not a manual for end users.

Comment: Yes, I know, but some of the description will be this same, and we want to do it the fastest way possible. With only one place and maybe another annotation. And for that no function name is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For not showing function name (for example when using view) change method add_directive_header in autodoc.py. I added, for now, return in the first line of this method.